# How to check content of varaible on integer/string/boolean?

Tags: angularjs, angular

How to check varibble on content type? For example I have rule string. It means that input variable sholud be `"string data"` not `0` or `"0"`.

I tried to do this as:

```
var status = false;

                    switch (node.value_type){

                        case "integer":
                            status = angular.isNumber(node.value);
                            break;
                    }
```

It always returns `false`

I tried this directive:

```
.directive('checkValueType', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                        var status = false;

                        var type_value = attrs.typeValue;

                        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {

                            switch (type_value){

                                case "integer":
                                    status = angular.isNumber(v);
                                    break;

                                case "string":
                                    status = (typeof v === 'string');
                                    break;

                                case "object":
                                    status = (typeof v === 'object');
                                    break;

                                case "array":
                                case "array_objects":
                                    status = (v instanceof Array);
                                    break;

                                case "boolean":
                                    status = (typeof v === 'boolean');
                                    break;

                                case "float":
                                    status = (Number(v) === n && n % 1 !== 0);
                                    break;

                                case "vector2":
                                    status = (v.length === 2);
                                    break;

                                case "vector3":
                                    status = (v.length === 3);
                                    break;
                            }

                            console.log("Type of " + typeof v);
                            console.log("Type: " + type_value);
                            console.log(status);

                        });
                    }
                };
            })
```

Comment: You can use `typeof`. Ex: `typeof node.value`

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>[#typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)</kbd>

```
switch(typeof(node.value_type)){

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with typeScript you can use  `typeOf` :

```
var status = false;
switch (typeof node){
   case "integer":
       status = angular.isNumber(node.value);
       break;
}
```

Comment: It always return false: console.log(node.type_value); // Integer
                                            console.log(typeof node.value); // String   `switch (node.type_value){

                        case "integer":
                            status = angular.isNumber(node.value);
                            break; }` I enter symbol: `900`

Comment: i have two questions : is the objectif of this algorithm just to test if a node is an integer or not ? what's the type of `node`?

Comment: I updated question. node is custom object, not DOM node